# add conditionally a column to a file awk

Tags: awk

I have a file that looks like this

```
--- 1:14567 14567 A C 0 0 1
--- 1:32424 34424 A C 0 0 1
rsid124 35245 C G 0 0 1
```

What I want is add a first field (`---`) only in those rows that don't already have the `---`

The desired output will be like this

```
--- 1:14567 14567 A C 0 0 1
--- 1:32424 34424 A C 0 0 1
--- rsid124 35245 C G 0 0 1
```

If it is easier, a workaround would be remove the `---` with vim or another text editor, but I would like to know how to add a column depending on row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paraphrased:

> What I want is add a first field `---` only in those rows that don't already have it.

This is quite easy to do with `awk`, just use:

```
awk '$1 != "---" { print "--- "$0 } { print }" inputFile >outputFile
```

This will modify all lines where the first column isn't as expected, prefixing it with the desired string. All other lines will be printed as is.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using sed, the following may work :

```
$ sed -i  's/^[^-]\(.*\)/--- \1/g' file.txt
```

Otherwise, an awk version would be like :

```
awk '{ if ( $1 == "---" ) { print $0 } else { print "---", $0 }   }' file.txt
```